# Is it ever correct to make the bracha of "mezonos" during Passover?

Tags: passover, matzah, mezonot-beracha

The bracha "bora m'nai mezonot" is usually said over food made from the five grains (wheat, barley, oats, rye, or spelt) that is not bread.  I have heard people say that one should **never** say this bracha during Pesach because we do not eat or even own any of these foods except for matzah.  I am not sure that this inference is true 100% of the time.  Are there any cases when one should say this bracha during Passover?

A few possibilities that you could confirm or deny (feel free to use other examples):

- Egg matzah (allowable for Sephardim and Ashkenazi children) is made with apple juice instead of water.  At the seder, a Sephardi would say "ha motzi" because the day takes precedence, but maybe not on chol ha moed or on the seventh and eighth day of the festival.
- A very small amount of matzah might not be enough to make a ha motzi on.
- If one used matzo meal to make chremslach (matzo-meal pancakes), the result is similar to a flour pancake that one would make a mezonot on the rest of the year.

It could be that the "never mezonos" statement holds up, but I would appreciate if it could be confirmed or shown to have exceptions.

Comment: If you don't hold of Gebrochts, also Matza balls.

Comment: **It could be that the "never mezonos" statement holds up** Egg matzah

Comment: It could be that the quote is from someone who's careful to not eat Gebrochts, which would make saying Mezonos hard, though  it's not clear if there's Gebrochts by fruit-juice (some are careful, others not).

Comment: Well, what about rice?

Comment: @Shokhet Good example.  I have no idea why we say mezonot on rice.  If I don't find the answer, I will post that as another question.

Comment: Related:  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15604/bracha-on-cooked-matza

Comment: About why we say mezonos on rice: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64865/5323

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70294/5275

Answer (score 2):

As you yourself said, there are lots of possibilities to say Mezonos on Pesach - the classic matzo-balls are a great example.

Any cake made from matza-meal is mezonos.

Sefardim (and other) who eat Kitniyot also have rice as a mezonos during Pesach.

**However**, those who don't eat gebroks/shruya (i.e. those who don't ever let the Matza come in contact with water) and don't eat Kitniyos have no opportunity to say Mezonos on Pessach. 

<sup>BTW: This custom was never heard of, nor documented, before the 1700's, [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebrochts).</sup>

Comment: Re. History of Gebrochts: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15645/732

Comment: To be fair, the 1700s were a long time ago.